# How to override default behavior of unstubbed void methods in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am mocking a fairly complex object hierarchy, and as I am working through it, there's a large number of methods that can be involved. If I miss and leave unstubbed a non-void method, Mockito by default makes it return null which quickly triggers a NPE and it's easy for me to locate it. However, if I miss a void method, the default behavior is to do nothing, which frequently leads to failures further downstream and much harder to debug. I'd like to change this default, e.g. throw a custom exception, but don't seem to find a way.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a default answer, passed in as a parameter to `Mockito.mock`. Unfortunately, due to limitations of Java annotations, it's not so easy to make this default behavior for `@Mock`-annotated fields.

```
public static class ThrowingAnswer implements Answer<Object> {
  @Override public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    if (invocation.getMethod().getReturnType() == Void.TYPE) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format(
          "Method %s not stubbed on %s",
          invocation.getMethod().getName(),
          invocation.getMock()));
    }
    return Answers.RETURNS_DEFAULTS.answer(invocation);
  }
}

YourClass mockYourClass = Mockito.mock(YourClass.class, new ThrowingAnswer());
```

Though you would be forced to use `doAnswer()` syntax for `void` methods anyway, be aware *if you change the above to include non-void methods* that you will be forced to use `doReturn()` syntax. This is because `when(foo.bar()).thenReturn(baz)` relies on the call to `foo.bar()` within the `when()` statement, but you will have stubbed it to throw an exception.

Also, if you find it hard to tell which void methods are relevant to stub on an external-enough-to-mock service, it may be a code smell that your service is doing to much, or that your system-under-test's interactions are not defined well enough. If you find yourself in this situation often, it may be time to document, refactor, or both.